# Laravel fill not setting component property

Tags: php, laravel

I have run into an issue with Laravel that hopefully someone could help explain. The fill command is not setting the properties of the model, and instead can only be used to save them to the database with the `->save()` function. Is there a way to do `fill` where it actually sets the properties of the model from an array.

Example of problem below.

```php
$comment = new comment();
$comment->fill(['name' => 'Bob']);
echo($comment->name); // Gives null/error.
```

```php
$comment = new comment();
$comment->name = 'Bob';
echo($comment->name); // Gives Bob.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is name filed is not fillable in comment model .To Solve this issue you have to add fillable for that field in comment model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name',

    ];
```

If you try to access non fillable field then it will return null.

If don't want to add it in fillable then you can use  `forceFill`.

**forceFill**: Fill the model with an array of attributes with force mass assignment.

```
$comment = new comment();
$comment->forceFill(['name' => 'Bob']);
echo($comment->name);
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect. I added another one to add more detail to it :) Honestly, I feel that Laravel should add more documentation on force property.

Comment: @Ravi yes  i read already and voted too. i add actually commented on your answer but its not visible  now not sure how.But your points also important one

Comment: Thank you! I already had the property in the fillabe, but I didn't know about the function forceFiill, and when I tried running it, I got an error saying it didn't exist. After more digging, and stupidity on my part, this was because I was including the Comment() as "Use App\Models\Comment as CommentModel;" since another class was called Comment in the same file. So to fix my issue I had to do "$comment = new CommentModel();" But your answer still helped me figure that out, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to use `fillable` property of the model and need to add `name` inside `fillable` array. That's the recommended way to do it.

As suggested by [John Lobo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68387581/4198099), You can forcibly override that mechanism using `forceFill` or `forceCreate`.
Both ignores fillable property in the model. It may possible that you may have a column like `is_admin` and you do not want to update it but force will do it.

**Notes** :

1. The main problem with `forceCreate` or `forceFill`, is that we have to manage the foreign key assignment manually.
2. `forceFill` will do fill (properties) only. You need save method call to save the actual record while `forceCreate` will do fill (properties) and Save both together.